# Append multiple input values into a div at specific positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Goal: Enable the user to link form fields to specific locations in a content from a different div and then append the individual input fields' text to those specific locations respectively.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orzd8uv5/7/)

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div>
        <label for="1">One:</label>
        <input type="text" id="1" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="2">Two:</label>
        <input type="email" id="2" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="3">Three:</label>
        <input type="email" id="3" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="4">Four:</label>
        <input type="email" id="4" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="5">Five:</label>
        <input type="email" id="5" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="6">Six:</label>
        <input type="email" id="6" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="7">Seven:</label>
        <input type="email" id="7" />
    </div>
</form>

<div class="text-area">
    <p>asd</p>
    <p>asd</p>
    <p>asd</p>
    <p>asd</p>
    <p>asd</p>
    <p>asd</p>
    <p>asd</p>
</div>
```

Js:

```
    function replaceText() {
        var thisvalue = $(this).val();
        var thisattr = $(this).siblings('label').attr('for');
        //alert(thisvalue);
        $('.text-area p').each(function(){
        $(this).text(function () {
        return $(this).text().replace("["+thisattr+"]", "["+thisvalue+"]"); 
            }); 
        });
    }
```

In the fiddle, click on the text "asd", that will enable you to type anything. You will see, that once you enter a value in the input tag beside "One:", it replaces the text as required. What I could think of as of now, is, to type a "tag" that is enclosed between square brackets, and then the function compares the tag with the input's label attr "for" and replaces it with the input value. There is one major flaw to this: the user has to tag again and again for the same input every time they want to change the value, which renders the form useless because why won't they just type the information directly rather than using the form.

This comes close, if not identical, to the way stackoverflow itself creates the link tags, image tags etc in the text box when we type in here to ask questions.

Comment: At least add a comment if you are going to down rate it.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you want to achieve is similar to Angular JS, where realtime update happens when you are typing in a text box.

If not, you can use **oninput** event. You can have a span tag or a placeholder next to your "Asd" and just replace your placeholder innertext with the text of the control